# Append HTML Table To Json Response In Codeigniter

Tags: json, ajax, codeigniter

Hi I Want to draw a table with json data which is my code I am getting correct json response but not able to draw a table in popup, Which is my Code

```
$(document).on('click','.details', function(){
var student_id = $(this).attr("id");
//alert(Id);
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url(user/details);?>",
      type: "post",
      data: {id:id},
      success: function(data)
            { 
    $.each(json, function (i,data) {
        $("#fees_table").append( "<tr><td>" + data.name + "</td><td>" + data.first_name + "</td><td>" + data.last_name + "</td><td>" + data.user_name + "</td></tr>");
    });

            }
    });
 } );
```

Which is my controller
    And My model is

```
public function getStudentFees($student_id)
{
    $query=$this->db->select('name,first_name,last_name,user_name')->from('users');
    $result= $query->result_array();
    //echo $this->db->last_query();die();
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
$.each(json, function (i,data) {
    //....
});
```

as

```
var data = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(data, function (i) {
    $("#fees_table").append( "<tr><td>" + data[i].name + "</td><td>" + data[i].first_name + "</td><td>" + data[i].last_name + "</td><td>" + data[i].user_name + "</td></tr>");
});
```

If you getting correct response then it should work

Comment: Thank you @Rejoanul Alam, But I am getting Uncaught Reference Error: json is not defined

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '516' in

Comment: then you should parse your json data, as you are getting json string. check my edited answer

Comment: excellent @rejoanul, Now Table is coming but json data also showing correct in console but In table the fields are showing undefined. Anything wrong??

Comment: then show your `console.log(data)` values & `details` method code of `user` controller

Comment: [{"id":"3","name":kiran","first_name":varun","last_name":arun","user_name":kiran"},{"id":"3","name":jagan","first_name":ravi","last_name":arjun","user_name":varun"}]

Comment: public function details()
    { 
        $id=$this->input->post('student_id');
        $userdetails=$this->users->getdetails($id);
        echo json_encode($userdetails);
    }

Comment: you may edit your answer to show `getdetails()` models's method code. it is necessary because I need to see how your data structured

Comment: ok, I have edited my answer too. check it. now hope your problem solved

Answer (score 0):

add dataType to your ajax options

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url(user/details);?>",
      type: "post",
      data: {id:id},
dataType: "json", // convert response data to json 
      success: function(data)
            { 
    $.each(json, function (i,data) {
        $("#fees_table").append( "<tr><td>" + data.name + "</td><td>" + data.first_name + "</td><td>" + data.last_name + "</td><td>" + data.user_name + "</td></tr>");
    });

            }
    });
```